# Facebook API to create a marketplace listing

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Spent too much time on Facebook API documentation, only similar thing I found was through eCommerce/Business page, but I need to do without business
When manually adding a post it goes to https://www.facebook.com/api/graphql/
Can't figure out how to reverse engineer the request.

Tried making curl requests, the graph API Explorer to no avail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.